# Can someone explain how does step 1 render to step 2?

Tags: induction, factorial, factoring

(1)$(n+1)!−1+(n+1)×(n+1)!$

(2)$=(1+n+1)×(n+1)!−1$

(3)$=(n+2)×(n+1)!−1 $

(4)$=(n+2)!−1$

I understand how step 4 derived from 3, but I am confused on how does step 2 derived from step 1? thank you

Comment: Factor out the $(n+1)!$ from the two terms that have it. So, use commutativity of addition and subtraction to move the $-1$ to the end, then you have $1\times (n+1)!+(n+1)\times (n+1)!-1$.

Comment: Take out common factor $(n+1)!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a\times c + b\times c = (a+b)\times c$

$c = 1\times c$

Now, use the above with $1$ in place of $a$, with $(n+1)$ in place of $b$ and $(n+1)!$ in place of $c$ to get:

$(n+1)! + (n+1)\times (n+1)! = 1\times (n+1)! + (n+1)\times (n+1)! = (1+n+1)\times (n+1)!$